# Can't lint python files with autopep8

Tags: python, python-3.x, autopep8, pycodestyle

I have the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/autopep8", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 4528, in main
    results = fix_multiple_files(args.files, args, sys.stdout)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 4423, in fix_multiple_files
    ret = _fix_file((name, options, output))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 4393, in _fix_file
    return fix_file(*parameters)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 3589, in fix_file
    fixed_source = fix_lines(fixed_source, options, filename=filename)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 3569, in fix_lines
    fixed_source = fix.fix()
                   ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 613, in fix
    self._fix_source(filter_results(source=''.join(self.source),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 557, in _fix_source
    modified_lines = fix(result)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 761, in fix_e225
    pycodestyle.missing_whitespace_around_operator(fixed, ts))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pycodestyle' has no attribute 'missing_whitespace_around_operator'. Did you mean: 'whitespace_around_operator'?
```

This is the version of autopep8

```
autopep8 --version
autopep8 2.0.2 (pycodestyle: 2.11.0)
```

Comment: There is an issue related to this error in autopep8 repo https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/issues/689

Comment: Ok, thx, missed that.